# General programs/libraries for studying user search behavior?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, search, library

Are there any general open-source programs or libraries (e.g., a Python library) for analyzing user search behavior?  By "search behavior", I mean a user's interaction with a search engine, such as querying, clicking relevant results, and spending time on those results.  I'd like something with the following properties - it doesn't have to be all of them, but the more the merrier:

- Models individual user behavior (aggregate and time-based)
- Models group user behavior
- Simulates individual user behavior, given a model
- Is easily extensible (to accept data input formats, user models, document models, etc., that end-users define)

Links are a plus!

Answer (score 1):

I know of few though they do not model user behavior, they just try to present best search results and compare to user ideal. lemurproject.org has books based on it though it is old and in java. For example the user activity recorder works with firefox pre big numbers versioning. That is something like 10 years ago. Maybe has a modeler but almost certainly out of date. Apache Lucene is simpler though made for bigger data sets and regularly updated. [Terrier IR platform](https://github.com/terrier-org/terrier-core/blob/5.x/doc/index.md) is similar.